# How to order an array based on dates?

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have the following array

```
$dates = array(
    '2015-02-13',
    '2015-04-21',
    '2015-08-18',
    '2015-11-26',
    '2015-09-15',
    '2015-01-07',
    '2015-02-11',
    '2015-07-14',
    '2015-03-02',
);
```

I would like to sort this array from longest ago to most recent date.

```
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    // The logic I need
}
```

Could you help me out?

#### Edit

I would like to note that the date format can vary. To elaborate, I have dates in my database formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`, `YYYY/MM/DD`, `DD-MM-YYYY` and `DD/MM/YYYY`.

But as suggested below I can reformat the date and build a new array. So this will probably not be an issue.

Comment: If the format of the date can vary, and '2015-02-01' sometimes means 'February 1st' and sometimes 'January 2nd', it is complete chaos

Comment: @Peter I said that's a whole _other_ question.  Your edit has invalidated every answer you've had so far, because now this is more a question of how to convert arbitrary date formats to a comparable form, not about sorting them.

Comment: @Alnitak You are right, I edited some more telling that the reformatting will not be a problem.

Comment: @Peter See the updated answer now

Comment: @Peter ok, that's better, but for your own sanity you really should ensure that all dates are put into ISO8601 format _before_ they're stored in the database.

Comment: Remember it's cycle. day has value of 1, month has value of 32 and year 367, it might help you to sort this data :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dates you have are in shortened ISO8601 format, i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`.

These have the nice feature that the lexical sort order is the same as date order. So, just sort the array using the default sort function. It'll work.

When handling date strings inside code it's always a good idea to have ISO8601 be the canonical internal date format. Convert user-supplied to that as soon as possible, and if the user requires output to be in their own locale then defer that to as late as possible. Of course, using a "proper" date object is better still!

Answer (score 2):

Just try to convert all date formats to time numbers.

```
<?php
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($datesInFormatA as $date) {
    $finalArray[] = strtotime($date);
}
foreach ($datesInFormatB as $date) {
    $finalArray[] = strtotime($date);
}
```

And for all of your date formats do this. Then you will have an array of numbers that you can sort them easily.

```
$finalArray = sort($finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function

```
<?php
$dates = array(
    '2015-02-13',
    '2015-04-21',
    '2015-08-18',
    '2015-11-26',
    '2015-09-15',
    '2015-01-07',
    '2015-02-11',
    '2015-07-14',
    '2015-03-02',
);

sort($dates);

var_dump($dates);
```

Output:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2015-01-07"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2015-02-11"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2015-02-13"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2015-03-02"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "2015-04-21"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "2015-07-14"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "2015-08-18"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "2015-09-15"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "2015-11-26"
}
```

Remember, this works for 'Y-m-d' format. For other formats you need to convert to date format using strtotime() function and need to proceed. Something like this (standard formats):

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a[0]) - strtotime($b[0]);
}
usort($dates, "sortFunction");
```

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

Comment: What date format, it can be changed to date format using strtotime function

Comment: @Peter that's a whole other question

Answer (score 1):

You can convert with `strtotime()` to safely date-manipulating and then you can reorder the array:

```
$dates = array(
    '2015-02-13',
    '2015-04-21',
    '2015-08-18',
    '2015-11-26',
    '2015-09-15',
    '2015-01-07',
    '2015-02-11',
    '2015-07-14',
    '2015-03-02',
);
$newArray = array();

foreach($dates as $value) {
    $newArray[] = strtotime($value);
}

sort($newArray);

var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you mentioned that you have all your dates in the following formats: YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY/MM/DD, DD-MM-YYYY and DD/MM/YYYY

First you will need to convert them to a single format, lets use YYYY-MM-DD.
Then as already mentioned, you will just need to regular sort it.

Included how you could re format your strings, without having to create a date object per each just for sorting.

```
  $dates = array(
        '2015-02-13',
        '2015-04-21',
        '2015-08-18',
        '2015-11-26',
        '2015-09-15',
        '2015/01/07',
        '2015-02-11',
        '2015/07/14',
        '2015-03-02',
        '08/01/2015',
        '08-04-2015',
    );

array_walk($dates, function(&$el){
    if($el[4] !== '-' && $el[4] !== '/'){
        // Ugly, I know, but is the fastest
        $el = $el[6] . $el[7] .$el[8] . $el[9] . '-' . $el[3] . $el[4] . '-' . $el[0] . $el[1]; 
        // Or just explode, revert array and implode
    }elseif($el[4] !== '-'){
        $el = str_replace('/', '-', $el);
    }
});
sort($dates);
print_r($dates);
```

Will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-01-07
    [1] => 2015-01-08
    [2] => 2015-02-11
    [3] => 2015-02-13
    [4] => 2015-03-02
    [5] => 2015-04-08
    [6] => 2015-04-21
    [7] => 2015-07-14
    [8] => 2015-08-18
    [9] => 2015-09-15
    [10] => 2015-11-26
)
```

Want it to other way, just use `rsort($dates)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this quick sort algorithm.
What it does is, it compares the date as `Unix Timestamp` which starts from `Jan 01 1970 (UTC))` and sort it and put into the array.

Converting to `Unix Timestamp` asures the `ISO8601` date format.

```
$dates = array(
    '2015-02-13',
    '2015-04-21',
    '2015-08-18',
    '2015-11-26',
    '2015-09-15',
    '2015-01-07',
    '2015-02-11',
    '2015-07-14',
    '2015-03-02',
);

function quick_sort($array)
{
    // find array size
    $length = count($array);

    // base case test, if array of length 0 then just return array to caller
    if($length <= 1){
        return $array;
    }
    else{

        // select an item to act as our pivot point, since list is unsorted first position is easiest
        $pivot = $array[0];

        // declare our two arrays to act as partitions
        $left = $right = array();

        // loop and compare each item in the array to the pivot value, place item in appropriate partition
        for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++)
        {
            if(strtotime($array[$i]) < strtotime($pivot)){
                $left[] = $array[$i];
            }
            else{
                $right[] = $array[$i];
            }
        }

        // use recursion to now sort the left and right lists
        return array_merge(quick_sort($left), array($pivot), quick_sort($right));
    }
}

$sorted = quick_sort($dates);
print_r($sorted);
```

// Output

```
Array
(
    [0] 2015-01-07
    [1] 2015-02-11
    [2] 2015-02-13
    [3] 2015-03-02
    [4] 2015-04-21
    [5] 2015-07-14
    [6] 2015-08-18
    [7] 2015-09-15
    [8] 2015-11-26
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution for you, hope this will help you to sort as this is working for me.

I recommend you to use `usort()` With a custom function:

```
$dates = array(
    '2015-02-13',
    '2015-04-21',
    '2015-08-18',
    '2015-11-26',
    '2015-09-15',
    '2015-01-07',
    '2015-02-11',
    '2015-07-14',
    '2015-03-02',
);

function date_fun_compare($a, $b)
    {
        $t1 = strtotime($a['datetime']);
        $t2 = strtotime($b['datetime']);
        return $t1 - $t2;
    }    
    usort($dates, 'date_fun_compare');
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

php does not work well in format `MM DD YYYY` because of the confusion between `day` and `month`.

For your first and second condition `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY/MM/DD` you can follow this solution:

```
$dates = array(
    '2015-02-13',
    '2015-04-21',
    '2015-08-18',
    '2015-11-26',
    '2015-09-15',
    '2015-01-07',
    '2015-02-11',
    '2015-07-14',
    '2015-03-02',
);

function date_sorter($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a);
    $t2 = strtotime($b);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}
usort($dates, 'date_sorter');

// check the output
echo '<pre>'.print_r($dates,1).'</pre>'
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
[0] => 2015-01-07
[1] => 2015-02-11
[2] => 2015-02-13
[3] => 2015-03-02
[4] => 2015-04-21
[5] => 2015-07-14
[6] => 2015-08-18
[7] => 2015-09-15
[8] => 2015-11-26
)
```

FYI: you can try changing `-` to `/`

If the format is like `YYYY DD MM` (whatever it is `/` or `-`) you can see the following solution:

Sample input:

```
$dates = array(
   '13/02/2015',
   '21/04/2015',
   '18/08/2015',
   '26/11/2015',
   '15/09/2015',
   '07/01/2015',
   '11/02/2015',
   '14/07/2015',
   '02/03/2015',
);
```

Function:

```
function date_sorter($a, $b )
{
   $da = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $a); // define date format d/m/Y
   $db = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $b);  // define date format d/m/Y

   $t1 = strtotime($da->format('Y-m-d'));
   $t2 = strtotime($db->format('Y-m-d'));
   return $t1 - $t2;
}
usort($dates, 'date_sorter');

echo '<pre>'.print_r($dates,1).'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 07/01/2015
   [1] => 11/02/2015
   [2] => 13/02/2015
   [3] => 02/03/2015
   [4] => 21/04/2015
   [5] => 14/07/2015
   [6] => 18/08/2015
   [7] => 15/09/2015
   [8] => 26/11/2015
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of your date (in your case is ok with Y-m-d) just perform a sort

```
sort($dates);
```

Comment: I'd really would like to know the reason for the downvote. That would help not to repeat the same error again.

Comment: not my downvote, but I'd hazard a guess that it's because `YYYY-MM-DD` is the _only_ date format where default lexical sort works.  For anything else you'd have to provide a custom comparator.